# Ошибка при установке pip pyside для python

Tags: python, pip, pyside

Не устанавливается только этот мод. Я новичок в программирование, пролистал много форумов, но не нашёл ничего с этой ошибкой. Вот что выдаёт cmd:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\it\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7botwn4n\\PySide\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dom\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7botwn4n\\PySide\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Dom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-zyx4om76'
         cwd: C:\Users\Dom\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7botwn4n\PySide\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: какая у версия `Python` ? Почему вы решили установить `PySide`, а не `PySide2` или `PyQt5` ?

Comment: Да, версии Python, допустимые для PySide ниже 3.5.